# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Sigh. Contentview size is zero. error getting xcode 9

Tags: objective-c, xcode9

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Sigh. Contentview size is zero.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bddc1ab __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010af2af41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bde1372 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010a9cf089 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000108e25134 -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS _contentViewFittingHeight] + 265
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000108ba5cc0 -[UINavigationItem _desiredHeightForBarMetrics:defaultHeightBlock:] + 90
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000108e27cf3 -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS heightRangeFittingWidth:] + 412
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000108342661 -[UINavigationBar _heightRangeForNavigationItem:fittingWidth:] + 210
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010841cc87 -[UINavigationController _intrinsicNavigationBarHeightRangeForViewController:] + 187
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010841cba5 -[UINavigationController _preferredHeightForHidingNavigationBarForViewController:] + 628
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010840cc93 -[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:edge:initialOffset:] + 356
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010840d0fc -[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:edge:] + 388
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000108414744 -[UINavigationController loadView] + 243
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001083d7495 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001083d7cf2 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    15  HAULMYGOODS                         0x0000000107b2e4fa -[SlideNavigationController setEnableShadow:] + 74
    16  HAULMYGOODS                         0x0000000107b2bea4 -[SlideNavigationController setup] + 244
    17  HAULMYGOODS                         0x0000000107b2bbe1 -[SlideNavigationController initWithCoder:] + 145
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001086be54c -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 246
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000108910a45 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010891077a -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010833ecce -[UINavigationBar initWithCoder:] + 753
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000108910a45 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010891077a -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000108ba0d49 -[UINavigationItem initWithCoder:] + 1018
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000108910a45 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010891077a -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    27  UIKit                               0x00000001083d248c -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 432
    28  UIKit                               0x00000001086be54c -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 246
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000108910a45 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    30  UIKit                               0x000000010891077a -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    31  UIKit                               0x00000001086be218 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 178
    32  UIKit                               0x00000001086be954 -[UIRuntimeEventConnection initWithCoder:] + 59
    33  UIKit                               0x0000000108910a45 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
    34  UIKit                               0x0000000108910be3 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1118
    35  UIKit                               0x000000010891077a -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
    36  UIKit                               0x00000001086bd415 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1262
    37  UIKit                               0x0000000108b4a0de -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181
    38  UIKit                               0x0000000108231dde -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 112
    39  UIKit                               0x0000000108232295 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 228
    40  UIKit                               0x00000001082309ca -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1413
    41  UIKit                               0x00000001085f62e0 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 924
    42  UIKit                               0x00000001089c8be0 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
    43  UIKit                               0x00000001085f5ed9 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 249
    44  UIKit                               0x00000001085f6737 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 668
    45  UIKit                               0x0000000108f6ac4d __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 262
    46  UIKit                               0x0000000108f6ab06 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 444
    47  UIKit                               0x0000000108c4bd52 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 420
    48  UIKit                               0x0000000108e48a7e _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
    49  UIKit                               0x0000000108c4bb4e -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 231
    50  UIKit                               0x00000001089c823d -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
    51  UIKit                               0x000000010822f37e -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 523
    52  UIKit                               0x0000000108803c1b -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 369
    53  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010ddbd158 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 338
    54  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010ddc5c4d __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 235
    55  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011088643c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    56  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011088baf4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
    57  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010ddf1672 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    58  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010ddf1328 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 464
    59  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010ddf1897 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    60  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd7f231 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    61  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010be1ee41 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
    62  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd63b49 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
    63  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd6312f __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
    64  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd629b9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    65  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010eaa09c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    66  UIKit                               0x00000001082325e8 UIApplicationMain + 159
    67  HAULMYGOODS                         0x0000000107b2ba3f main + 111
    68  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110902d81 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Did you see the exception reason *Contentview size is zero*? It's quite meaningful.

Comment: app getting crashed while running with xcode 9 but its working xcode 8 this above error code getting from console

Comment: Anyone know this issue?